Order of events is invariant in timelike intervals
I thought that the order of events could be something that changes with a boost. But recently, I read in a book that for time-like separated events, the order of events is invariant.
If I think about a boost and start with $c \Delta t' < 0$ (i.e., the events are reversed in that frame), I arrive at $\Delta s^2 < 0$, which means they must be space-like separated.
What confuses me is that I imagined there were 2 trains, side by side, close enough for a lightning to hit the ground where Bob is, Alice's train, and another train where another observer, $C$, is located.
If $C$ moves in the opposite direction to Alice, it is the ray on the left that arrives first. In that case, the order of events changes. Bob says the events happen simultaneously, Alice says the ray on the right arrives first, and $C$ says the ray on the left arrives first.
In this case, I would think that the order of events is not invariant, which does not align with my initial reasoning because $C$ would not need to move at speeds greater than $c$, only in the opposite direction to $A$.

The two lightning strikes are space-like separated, not time-like. Order of events is invariant only for time-like separated events.

Eric's comment is correct. If two spatially separated events are simultaneous in some frame, then they must be space like separated, so their order can be reversed in other frames. If they were time like separated, then they could not be simultaneous according to Bob.
Loosely speaking, space like separation means that light from one event doesn't have enough time to reach the other. Clearly if two lightning flashes are simultaneous in Bob's frame, then light from one of the flashes cannot reach the other flash, since the other flash is over before the light has a chance to get to it.

So the velocity needed to go from one event to the other is greater than 1, but the velocity of the boost to a frame where the events are reversed is not necessarily greater than 1.

Yes. To travel between two simultaneous events you would need infinite speed.

You have set this problem up in the most confusing way possible. It's best to address these things systematically, with actual events using coordinates, not just ambiguous sentences.
Now we have 3 frames in this problem, that are going to be assigned to Alice, Bob and Chuck, and we're going to call them $S$, $S'$ and $S''$, respectively.
Rule 1: Start in the "rest" frame, at the top of the alphabet with the fewest "primes" in $S$.
(Of course, the point of relativity is that there is no absolute rest frame, but we have a natural one associated with the train station, so we're calling that $S$, the "rest" frame).
And that is Alice. Always start at rest.
We also follow the tradition of the $x$ axis pointing to the right (no really, ppl will describe their problems with sentences only and discover $x$ points left), and we introduce the traditional second train moving in that direction at $\beta$. That is Bob's train in $S'$.
Now you added a 3rd train, so that goes to Chuck ($S''$) moving to the left at $\beta$, which is, according to Alice, $-\beta$.
Rule 2: All origins must be the same. All frames have an event call the origin, $O$, and they are labeled as follows:
$$ O = (0, 0)_S = (0, 0)_{S'} = (0, 0)_{S''} $$
where the coordinates are labeled per tradition:
$$ (t, x)_{\rm Frame} $$
Now you mention a lightning strike, but there appears to be 2 strikes, at the ends of the trains, which I am going to label $+$ and $-$ based on their space coordinate. Maybe that's not the best choice but we have Chuck going the wrong way, so "Engine/Caboose" or "Front/Back" could get confusing.
I am going to now label those events according to Alice:
$$ E_{\pm} = (0, \pm D)_S $$
where $D = \frac 1 2 \frac L {\gamma} $ ($L$ is the length of the train).
The invariant interval is:
$$ \Delta s_0^2 = (E_+-E_-)^2 = -(D-(-D))^2 = -4D^2 < 0 $$
so these are space-like separated, and hence: not time ordered.
For fun, I'll add a 3rd event that has a time-like separation from $O$. Let make that the event of Alice detecting the lightning stikes' flashes:
$$ E_1 = (D, 0)_S $$
which has a time-like separation from the origin:
$$ \Delta s_1^2 = (E_1-O)^2 = +(D-0)^2 = D^2 $$
which means all frames say $E_1$ occurred after $O$.
Now we can transform the lightning strikes. According to Bob:
$$ t_{\pm}' = \gamma(t_{\pm} -\beta x_\pm) $$
$$ t_{\pm}' = \mp\gamma\beta D $$
and
$$ x'_{\pm} = \gamma(x_{\pm} - \beta t_{\pm}) $$
$$ x'_{\pm} = \pm\gamma D $$
So:
$$ E_{\pm} = 
\Big(
\mp\gamma\beta \frac L 2, \pm\frac L 2
\Big)
$$
which means the front of his train is struck 1st.
Meanwhile, Chuck sees:
$$ E_{\pm} = 
\Big(
\pm\gamma\beta \frac L 2, \pm\gamma \frac L 2
\Big)_{S'}
$$
so the front of his train is also struck 1st. (Note: this is required by parity, since Chuck is the mirror image of Bob, and relativity is parity invariant).
Note: since I chose $D$ wisely, we see that Bob and Chuck see that the lengths of their trains are both $L$, the proper lengths of that trains.
For a timelike interval, we transform the coordinates of Alice's detection of the strikes. Bob sees:
$$ t_1' = \gamma(t_1 -\beta x_1) $$
$$ t_1' = \gamma D = L/2 $$
and
$$ x'_1 = \gamma(x_1 - \beta t_1) $$
$$ x'_1 = -\beta\gamma D = -\beta\frac L 2$$
so (including Chuck's transform)
$$ E_1 = \Big(
\frac L 2, -\beta\frac L 2
\Big)_{S'} = \Big(
\frac L 2, +\beta\frac L 2
\Big)_{S''}
$$
So Bob and Chuck see $E_1$ after $O$, which is required, since Alice's detection of $E_{\pm}$ at $E_1$ is casually connected to the events at $E_{\pm}$.
For fun, you can show that the detection of an event by its light signal is null separated from the event(s):
$$ \Delta s^2 \equiv (E_1 - E_{\pm})^2 = 0 $$
That is, events on the past light-cone of $E_1$ are on the past light-cone in all frames.
